# UIWebView Facebook button liked

Tags: ios, uiwebview, facebook-like

I have a small subview in which Facebook like button exists using UIWebView. I want to hide my subView whenever user hits the facebook like button.
In short I want to trig an event whenever facebook like button is pressed. The button is in UIWebView.